# Error while downloading & saving image to sd card in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am working on blackberry project where i want to download image & save it in sd card in blackberry. By going through many sites i got some code & based on that i wrote the program but when it is executed the output screen is displaying a blank page with out any response. The code i am following is..

code:

```
    public class BitmapDemo extends UiApplication
   {    
      public static void main(String[] args)
        {        
       BitmapDemo app = new BitmapDemo();
       app.enterEventDispatcher();        
   }
   public BitmapDemo()
   {
       pushScreen(new BitmapDemoScreen());
   }

      static class BitmapDemoScreen extends MainScreen
    {
       private static final String LABEL_X = " x ";
       BitmapDemoScreen()
        {
        //BitmapField bmpFld1=new BitmapField(connectServerForImage("http://images03.olx.in/ui/3/20/99/45761199_1.jpg"));
        //add(bmpFld1);
        setTitle("Bitmap Demo");    

        // method for saving image in sd card
        copyFile();    

        // Add a menu item to display an animation in a popup screen
        MenuItem showAnimation = new MenuItem(new StringProvider("Show Animation"), 0x230010, 0);
        showAnimation.setCommand(new Command(new CommandHandler() 
        {
            public void execute(ReadOnlyCommandMetadata metadata, Object context) 
            {
                // Create an EncodedImage object to contain an animated
                // gif resource.      
                EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("animation.gif");

                // Create a BitmapField to contain the animation
                BitmapField bitmapFieldAnimation = new BitmapField();
                bitmapFieldAnimation.setImage(encodedImage);               

                // Push a popup screen containing the BitmapField onto the
                // display stack.
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new BitmapDemoPopup(bitmapFieldAnimation));                    
            }
        }));

        addMenuItem(showAnimation);       
    }        

    private static class BitmapDemoPopup extends PopupScreen
    {    
        public BitmapDemoPopup(BitmapField bitmapField)
        {
            super(new VerticalFieldManager());                           
            add(bitmapField);                
        } 
        protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) 
        {
            if(c == Characters.ESCAPE)
            {
                close();
            }               
            return super.keyChar(c, status, time);
        }
    }
}

public static Bitmap connectServerForImage(String url) {

    System.out.println("image url is:"+url);
    HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
    DataOutputStream httpDataOutput = null;
    InputStream httpInput = null;
    int rc;
    Bitmap bitmp = null;
    try {
     httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE);
     rc = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
     if (rc != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
      throw new IOException("HTTP response code: " + rc);
     }
     httpInput = httpConnection.openInputStream();
     InputStream inp = httpInput;
     byte[] b = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(inp);
     EncodedImage hai = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(b, 0, b.length);
     return hai.getBitmap();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
     System.out.println("URL Bitmap Error........" + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
     try {
      if (httpInput != null)
       httpInput.close();
      if (httpDataOutput != null)
       httpDataOutput.close();
      if (httpConnection != null)
       httpConnection.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
    return bitmp;
   }


public static void copyFile() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EncodedImage encImage = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("rim.png"); 
            byte[] image = encImage.getData();
            try {

                // Create folder if not already created
                FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/images/");
                if (!fc.exists())
                    fc.mkdir();
                fc.close();

             // Create file
                fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/images/" + image, Connector.READ_WRITE);
                if (!fc.exists())
                    fc.create();
                OutputStream outStream = fc.openOutputStream();
                outStream.write(image);
                outStream.close();
                fc.close();
                System.out.println("image saved.....");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                //System.out.println("exception is "+ e);
            }
}
```

}

This is the code which i am using. Not getting any response except blank page.. As i am new to blackberry development unable to find out what is the problem with my code. Can anyone please help me with this......  Actually i am having other doubt as like android & iphone does in blackberry simulator supports for SD card otherwise we need to add any SD card slots for this externally...

Waiting for your reply.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply download and save that image to the SDCard, you can use this code.  I changed your SDCard path to use the **pictures** folder, which I think is the standard location on BlackBerrys.  If you really want to store it in **images**, you may just need to create the folder if it doesn't already exist.

```java
package com.mycompany;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;

public class DownloadHelper implements Runnable {

   private String _url;

   public DownloadHelper(String url) {
      _url = url;
   }

   public void run() {
      HttpConnection connection = null;
      OutputStream output = null;
      InputStream input = null;
      try {
         // Open a HTTP connection to the webserver
         connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(_url);
         // Getting the response code will open the connection, send the request,
         // and read the HTTP response headers. The headers are stored until requested.
         if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            input = new DataInputStream(connection.openInputStream());
            int len = (int) connection.getLength();   // Get the content length
            if (len > 0) {
               // Save the download as a local file, named the same as in the URL
               String filename = _url.substring(_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
               FileConnection outputFile = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/" + filename, 
                     Connector.READ_WRITE);
               if (!outputFile.exists()) {
                  outputFile.create();
               }
               // This is probably not a robust check ...
               if (len <= outputFile.availableSize()) {
                  output = outputFile.openDataOutputStream();
                  // We'll read and write this many bytes at a time until complete
                  int maxRead = 1024;  
                  byte[] buffer = new byte[maxRead];
                  int bytesRead;

                  for (;;) {
                     bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
                     if (bytesRead <= 0) {
                        break;
                     }
                     output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                  }
                  output.close();
               }
            }
         }
      } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         try {
            if (output != null) {
               output.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
               connection.close();
            }
            if (input != null) {
               input.close();
            }
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // do nothing
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This class can download an image in the background, as I suggested.  To use it, you can start a worker thread like this:

```java
DownloadHelper downloader = new DownloadHelper("http://images03.olx.in/ui/3/20/99/45761199_1.jpg");
Thread worker = new Thread(downloader);
worker.start();
```

This will save the file as /SDCard/BlackBerry/pictures/45761199_1.jpg.  I tested it on a 5.0 Storm simulator.

Comment: Hi @Nate, it's very kind of you & thanks for posting the code. I tested the code in Blackberry 9930 simulator(7.0 version) its not working in it (not displaying anything except blank page). And then i tested it in Blackberry 9800 simulator(6.0 version) its working fine in it. Not getting any idea what's the problem is. Can you help me with this...

Comment: @code_finder, it's very hard to help without good, specific information about the problem.  If you want to download an image, save it to SDCard, and then display it, there are multiple places where that could have problems.  You need to tell us where the problem is happening (downloading, saving, displaying, etc.).  [Have a look at the information about asking questions on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  It sounds like this should be a new question.  If the code I posted works for you, but not on all simulators, start a new question about that specific problem.

Comment: k then, i will post new question based on the problem i am facing now.... Thanks for your suggestion Nate..........

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the code posted.  It's also not completely clear what you're trying to do.  From the question title, I assume you want to download a jpg image from the internet, and display it.

**1)** You implement a method called `connectServerForImage()` to download an image, but then it's commented out.  So, the method isn't going to download anything if it's not called.

**2)** Even if it's uncommented, `connectServerForImage()` is called here

```java
BitmapField bmpFld1=new BitmapField(connectServerForImage("http://images03.olx.in/ui/3/20/99/45761199_1.jpg"));
```

This will block the main (UI) thread while it downloads your image.  Even though you *can* do it this way, it's not a good thing to do.  Instead, you could create a `Thread` to download the image as a background task, and then use `UiApplication.invokeLater()` to load the image into your `BitmapField` on the main/UI thread.

**3)** Your `copyFile()` method tries to copy a file named **rim.png**, which must be an image bundled with your application, and saves it to the SDCard.  Is this really what you want?  Do you want to save the downloaded image instead?  This method doesn't seem to be connected to anything else.  It's not saving the image downloaded from the internet, and the image it does save is never used anywhere else.

**4)** In `copyFile()`, this line

```
fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/images/" + image, Connector.READ_WRITE);
```

is passing a `byte[]` in as part of the filename to open (your variable named `image`).  You should probably be adding a `String` name to the end of your SDCard path.  As the code is, it's probably opening a file in the /SDCard/BlackBerry/images/ folder with a very long name that looks like a number.  Or it might fail entirely, if there are limits on the length of filenames.

**5)** In Java, it's not usually a good idea to make everything `static`.  Static should normally be used for constants, and for a very few methods like the `main()` method, which must be static.

Try to clean these things up, and then repost the code, and we can try to help you with your problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Nate for your advise. Actually here why i commented "connectServerForImage()" is, first i tried to save the image in sd card which was downloaded. It's not worked, then i took one image in image folder & i passed that image in "copyfile()" method for saving it in sd card. After that i changed connector.open() method to "Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/");" & saved file as i am converting my "rim.png" file to bytes[] image, i am passing that "image" at the end of sd card path. It is saving but when i am opening that image it showing nothing but just blank screen.

Comment: Actually i am new to blackberry & i am struggling with this thing from last two days onwards, please help me with this otherwise can you post some code or otherwise will you send some code to my mail. if means i will provide my e-mail id to you...

Comment: @code_finder, I understand.  Learning something new is difficult.  But, to help you, it's important for you to post the code that you are using **right now**, and tell us the **exact problem** you are having with that code.  If you post one set of code that's trying to do 3 different things, with pieces that are commented out, it makes it very hard for us to fix the problem.

Comment: @code_finder, ... and look at the problems I describe in my post.  For example, the line of code I show above in (4).  That line of code cannot possibly work, because you are passing the byte[] binary content of an image as the **name** of the image file.  That can never work, whether the image is a bundled resource, or a network image.  Again, please change the code to try to do only one thing (download image and display, or copy local image and display, but not both).

Comment: mainly what i want is to download an image from server and need to save that one in blackberry sd card... that is the main requirement @Nate